# Dynamic HTML/CSS Buttons

Tags: html, css, button, dynamic, responsive

I have a problem with my buttons, I am a beginner into HTML and CSS but I need it for a uni project, well at least the front page. I'm trying to make it pretty and I wanted to make my buttons "move" apart when you hover over them.

Best explained, when you mouse-over a button it will zoom and the other buttons will shift to either right or left to keep the margin so they don't overflow each other.

I've tried playing around with overflow and padding and margins :before :after sizes (but for % it simply breaks everything) I'm trying to stick to % values as I was told that those make the site more responsive to different screen sizes.

Here's the HTML part:

```html
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div id="buttonstuff">
    <button onclick="location.href='http://example.com'" type="button" class="main-button">A</button>
    <button onclick="location.href='http://example.com'" type="button" class="main-button">B</button>
    <button onclick="location.href='http://example.com'" type="button" class="main-button">C</button>
    <button onclick="location.href='http://example.com'" type="button" class="main-button">D</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 93vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #222;
  color: #eee;
}

#buttonstuff {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.main-button {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  color: rosybrown;
  border: 0.2em solid rosybrown;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  transition: transform .4s ease;
}

.main-button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

Also working [codepen](https://codepen.io/deviljin112/pen/PoYMJvR)

I'm not sure what to try, as my HTML / CSS Knowledge is pretty basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach keeping the margin between the buttons at exactly 5px and working on different screen sizes. It does not use transform's `scale()`, but increases several values like `padding` and `font-size` by a factor of 1.3 instead. Please note that the effect is slightly different from the original in that the animation isn't exactly centered on the button, especially noticeable on the outermost buttons. I haven't been able to address this, but this solution might still work for you.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 93vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #222;
  color: #eee;
}

#buttonstuff {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 88%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.main-button {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 200%;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  color: rosybrown;
  border: 0.2em solid rosybrown;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.main-button:hover {
  padding: 0em 1em;
  width: 130%;
  height: 130%;
  font-size: 260%;
  transform: translateY(-15%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="buttonstuff">
    <button onclick="location.href='http://example.com'" type="button" class="main-button">A</button>
    <button onclick="location.href='http://example.com'" type="button" class="main-button">B</button>
    <button onclick="location.href='http://example.com'" type="button" class="main-button">C</button>
    <button onclick="location.href='http://example.com'" type="button" class="main-button">D</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a better solution, makes it more responsive, thank you very much! Same question as for the solution below, how to remove that loading white default button which makes it look like im flashing the button in

Comment: I can't reproduce that effect, neither in the snippet here on SP, nor on codepen. I tried Firefox and Chrome (Windows).

Comment: Its only there for time of the transition (0.4s) [here is a link](https://imgur.com/B3ibq7O)

EDIT: im running opera, not sure if that matters, holding F5 literally makes it stay on screen the whole time. Again not sure of the cause

Answer (score 3):

If I understand, you will fix your problem with the code below:

```
.main-button {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  color: rosybrown;
  border: 0.2em solid rosybrown;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
    .main-button:hover {
      transform: scale(1.3);
      margin: 0 20px;
    }
```

Comment: You still get an overlap on larger window sizes, and the margin doesn't stay the same.

Comment: You can change the gap sizes, I just want to show a way. Exactly, he need to set right px s depending to window size.

Comment: you can use % instead px, average example : `margin: 0 4%;`

Comment: Solves the problem and is exactly what i need, but constantin made it more responsive, thank you for the input!

Comment: That sounds to me like a browser issue. Opera seems to render the whole page without any css first and then re-rendering with the CSS applied.

Answer (score 1):

i think it looks ok, otherwise it will move too much and be too noisy.

i would add this to your hover state:

```
.main-button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  background: #222;
  z-index:1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #333;
}
```

Additionally: every stylings within .button you can move into .main-button